# is there a way to write dynamic data to a file using File system (fs) in node.js. i have tried but in the file am receiving [object object]

Tags: node.js

i have an eventEmitter class (Logger) in another file that will log a message object with a uuid. i intend to write that message in a file.

```
const Logger = require('./Logger')
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')

// instantiate a new logger 

const logger = new Logger()

logger.on('message', data => {
    console.log('Called Listener:', data)

   fs.appendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/logger', 'logger.txt'), `\n ${data}`, err => {
        if (err) throw err
        console.log('file written...')
    })
   
})


logger.log('Hello there')
```

//any suggestions might help

Comment: What does `console.log()` print after 'Called listener'

Comment: `data` is an object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you can write an object out with console.log, you can't add it into a string without stringifying it:

```
fs.appendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/logger', 'logger.txt'), `\n ${JSON.stringify(data)}`, err => {
    if (err) throw err
    console.log('file written...')
})
```

What happens when you try to add a variable to a string is that the JS runtime implicitly calls .toString() on it. That will result in `[object object]` for an object.

Comment: Thank you boss for the help...now I know, keep up the good work

Answer (score 0):

Your logger is emitting an object, not a string. You probably need something more like `${data.uuid} - ${data.log}`.

More importantly, every time you append the file you're going through the work of requesting a new file descriptor from the OS and then closing it. This is inefficient and you create a race condition for yourself. If you were to do something like

```js
for(let i=0;i<1000;i++)
  logger.log(i.toString());
```

You would be highly unlikely to see 1000 lines in the file.

You want something more like

```js
const Logger = require('./Logger')
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')

// instantiate a new logger 

const logger = new Logger()

// Create write stream
const wstream = fs.createWriteStream(
  path.join(__dirname, '/logger', 'logger.txt'), 
  { 
    flags: 'a', // append to file
    autoClose: false // leave fd open for more writing after buffer empties
  }
);
logger.on('message', data => {
  console.log('Called Listener:', data)
  wstream.write(`${data.uuid} - ${data.log}\n`); 
})
```

Comment: thanks for the help.... i think the code works but its me having problems understanding it fully..i got some learning to do

Comment: Basically I'm saying you want to open a file and then just keep writing to it, rather than open->write->close, open->write->close, open->write->close, and on and on for the life of your program. Additionally, appending a file means you're reading the size of the file, and then writing at the end of it. In your implementation you can have `append A`, then `append B` read the size before `A` writes, thus overwriting anything `A` would have appended.

Comment: ndefined - undefined
undefined - undefined
undefined - undefined
undefined - undefined
undefined - undefined
undefined - undefined
undefined - undefined
undefined - undefined
undefined - undefined
undefined - undefined
undefined - undefined
undefined - undefined
undefined - undefined
undefined - undefined
undefined - undefined
undefined - undefined
undefined - undefined
undefined - undefined
undefined - undefined
undefined - undefined

Comment: Called Listener: { id: 'f45b4c5a-ffbc-4ef3-828d-f06dd9f06715', msg: '993' }

Comment: in the console its logging the data collectly but 999 times  also in the file  undefined-undefined is logging 999 times